# gcc console output color meanings

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am using gcc to compile some code. I notice that the console output color for successful builds are sometimes different.

For examples, I get the output:

> Linking C shared library libfoofuncs.so  (white on black background)

and sometimes, I get:

> Linking C shared library libfoobarfuncs.so  (bright red on black
>   background)

What do the different colors signify - should I ignore it?

I am developing using gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS

Comment: GCC 4.6 doesn't do coloured output. GCC 4.9 will, but that's not out yet. What are you *really* using?

Comment: @ams: On my machine: `gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`

Comment: Yes, but what build script are you using that adds the colors?

Comment: I am using CMake (v2.8). Its a simple CMakeLists.txt file with only the sources and includes added - nothing extra. I cant grok the Makefile generated by CMake though, my make fu is non-existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not GCC that produces these colors. [It's CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE). The colors are intended to make it more clear what's happening. When you see red, it means that something is being linked rather than compiled.

Unfortunately, the meaning of the colors aren't documented anywhere; there's no way to cite any documentation about why a link command would be shown in red in one case but not in another.

But in short: you don't need to worry about it.